Most reasonable interpretation of phrase "add an <a> to every <b>"?
Given a phrase with the construction add an <a> to every <b>, what is the most common or reasonable interpretation?

There are multiple <a> and we are adding a different one to each <b>.
There is one <a> and we are adding it to every <b>, so the single <a> is shared amonst all <b>.

If one is more favored than the other, by how much?

We could say "add the  to every " e.g. "Add the sauce to every pie" -- there is one bottle of sauce and we are using hot on each pie. But it would be more correct and natural to say "Put some sauce on every pie."

It probably depends on what  and  are.

Without context, there is no way to judge what the most common or reasonable interpretation might be. Voting to close.  We don't even know what the verb "add" means without context.

Please don't vote to close if the question shows a lack of understanding of how English works, such as being unaware that context is needed to clarify which interpretation is correct. Helping people learn this kind of thing is why ELL exists.

I didn't want to distract with context but it seems like it's hard to answer without more information. FWIW, two of the answers are very good and in line with what I was looking for.
The full context is that for a graph problem in math, some students (including ELLs) made a statement in their proofs along the lines of "add a star to every vertex", where a star is a center point connected to a few points. The graders said this statement was too vague to know that students meant adding an individual star instance to each vertex, rather than creating one star and attaching to every vertex.

I'm not sure if it's more appropriate to close this and post a new question with the full context, or leave it alone. I'm okay to close it if it is problematic.


We could say "add the  to every " e.g. "Add the sauce to every pie"

Yeah, but this seems like it is due to the difference between "a" and "the", right?

Nathan, please go ahead and add the additional context to the question. It will definitely help.

Meaning is determined by context more than by language structures. That said, I can't come up with any example sentence in which "add an A to every B" could possibly mean that a single A is shared among multiple Bs.

"Add a gumdrop to every cupcake"—no, that's impossible.
"Add a sheet of aluminum foil to every cinnamon roll"—It's so idiomatic that there's risk of confusion. A more common wording would be something like "Cover all the rolls with foil," maybe using "every" in a clarification like "make sure the foil covers every roll."

But beware, this has nothing to do with the structure; I guess it's just because of the semantic connotations of "add." After all, you'd be unlikely even to say "add a sheet of aluminum foil to the cinnamon rolls." I guess that's because the various meanings of "add" tend to emphasize that the new thing is being united with or merged with the the old thing; some definitions from Merriam-Webster include "to join or unite so as to bring about an increase or improvement" and "to combine (numbers) into an equivalent simple quantity or number." When you "add" A to B, A "joins" B so that the nature or identity of the result is something new. So if we're "adding" one A to lots of Bs, this sense doesn't pair well with "every," a word that emphasizes individuality. When we add the foil to the rolls, we're not performing a transformation on each roll, but on them all as a whole.

Add (i.e. append) a trademark symbol to every name on this list.  The issue of "single" and "sharing" is moot in that context. But you have introduced that issue owing to the lack of context, creating a context.

@TimR Hm, I would argue that even if there is a "single trademark," the symbols themselves are multiple ("add a glyph beside every name"). But yes, I could conceive of examples like "Add this disclaimer [singular] to every page of copy," but I would then argue that it stands for "Add an instance of this disclaimer."

The point is,it could be adding a bit of arsenic to every guest's dinner, a disclaimer to every ad, a state sales tax of 6% to every transaction amount,  whatever.  The question is so open-ended that it is merely a matter of opinion how to understand that little "formula".

This answer is the reasoning I follow. I cannot come up with any example sentence which results in one A shared by many B, whereas I can come up with many examples of one A instance per B instance.
"Add (i.e. append) a trademark symbol to every name on this list."
I agree with Andy, each trademark symbol here is a different instance or copy of the symbol.
"Adding a bit of arsenic to every guest's dinner."
It's not the same bit shared amongst all dinners, but a different bit in each one.

The most logical interpretation is

There are one or more <b> and each one is to have an <a> added to it.

For example

Add a scone  to every plate of cakes.


Add a free gift to every order over £50.


Thanks for the help, I agree and this makes sense to me :)

Interpretation 1 is likely the more favored one. The implication being that for every <b>, there exists a distinct <a> that will be given to it. This is one-to-one and onto, in mathematical terms. i.e., it's a bijection.
Exact figures on how much more it's favored would require data obtained from a study, but interpretation patterns in English indicate that the "each gets its own" understanding is dominant in phrases structured this way.
Mathier stuff (if you care)
In a bijection, we have both one-to-one (injective) and onto (surjective) mappings:
One-to-One (Injective): Each <b> has a unique <a> mapped to it, meaning no two <b>s share the same <a>. This uniqueness is why we think of each <b> as receiving its own <a>.

∀<a>1,<a>2, if f(<a>1)=f(<a>2), then <a>1 = <a>2

Onto (Surjective): Every <b> gets an <a>, meaning the set of <a>s completely covers the set of <b>s with no gaps. This ensures that each <b> has an <a> associated with it, aligning with the "every <b>" part of the phrase.

∀ <b>∈B, ∃ some <a>∈A such that f(<a>) = <b>.

In the context of the phrase "add an <a> to every <b>," thinking of it as a bijection captures both that each <b> has a corresponding <a> and that this mapping exhausts the set of <b>s, giving each one a unique <a> without redundancy or omission.
This makes Interpretation 1 naturally align with a bijective relationship, reinforcing why it is the more common interpretation.
Even more math
Problems could occur in that if this interpretation is the correct one, if there is a shortage in <a> s.t.
|<a>|[α] < |<b>|[],
then by pigeon hole principle not all <b> can receive an <a>.
This by definition means it's not a bijection.
[α] (the amount of <a>)
[β] (the amount of <b>)
